# Custom timer code needs reviewing for thread safety

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a custom timer to satisfy the following requirements:

- Millisecond accuracy
- I want the tick event handler to only be called once the current tick handler has completed (much like the winforms timer)
- I want exceptions on the main UI thread not to be swallowed up by the thread timer so this requires Invoke/Send instead of BeginInvoke/Post

Note: I call timeBeginPeriod(1)/ timeEndPeriod(1) in order to achieve the millisecond accuracy.

I've put in a check if the timer is deleted to make sure that the deletion is complete before the timer can be created again. Does that look ok?

For the *IsRunning* property, is it possible that racing conditions could occur?

...or is the code a disaster waiting to happen and I should try (again) to get CreateTimerQueueTimer to work?

The code has been tested with a small interval of 1 millisecond and a large interval of 300 milliseconds with frequent start/stops, and I've had no problems so far.

**ETA: I've found a problem with it. If the timer is running at an interval of 1 millisecond, and I call, say, Change(300), it locks up @ while (this.DeleteRequest). This 
must be because the TimerLoop is in the this.CallbackDelegate.Invoke(null) call.**

```
public class MyTimer : IDisposable
{

    private System.Threading.TimerCallback CallbackDelegate;
    private bool DeleteRequest;

    private System.Threading.Thread MainThread;
    public MyTimer(System.Threading.TimerCallback callBack)
    {
        this.CallbackDelegate = callBack;
    }


    public void Create(int interval)
    {
        while (this.DeleteRequest) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        if (this.MainThread != null) {
            throw new Exception("");
        }

        this.MainThread = new System.Threading.Thread(TimerLoop);
        // Make sure the thread is automatically killed when the app is closed.
        this.MainThread.IsBackground = true;
        this.MainThread.Start(interval);

    }

    public void Change(int interval)
    {
        // A lock required here?
        if (!this.IsRunning()) {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
        this.Delete();
        this.Create(interval);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        this.DeleteRequest = true;
    }

    public bool IsRunning()
    {
        return (this.MainThread != null) && this.MainThread.IsAlive;
    }


    private void TimerLoop(object args)
    {
        int interval = (int)args;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();


        do {
            if (this.DeleteRequest) {
                this.MainThread = null;
                this.DeleteRequest = false;
                return;
            }

            long t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            // I want to wait until the operation completes, so I use Invoke.
            this.CallbackDelegate.Invoke(null);

            if (this.DeleteRequest) {
                this.MainThread = null;
                this.DeleteRequest = false;
                return;
            }

            long t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Max(interval - (t2 - t1), 0));
            sw.Reset();
            if (temp > 0) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(temp);
            }

            sw.Start();
        } while (true);

    }

        // dispose calls this.Delete();

}
```

Comment: If you found a solution, please post an answer with it and accept it instead of editing your post. That way future visitors can easily see what your solution was.

Answer (score 1):

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() has an accuracy (resolution) of around 15 milliseconds, and so I would stay far away from using that in your code if you need millisecond accuracy. Can you use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead? - this uses a high resolution timer where available, by default. You might find this post on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631501/need-microsecond-delay-in-net-app-for-throttling-udp-multicast-transmission-rate) useful as well.